# ImportError: cannot import name 'model_to_dot'

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I want to visualize Keras model using Google Colab environment. I found [this link](https://keras.io/visualization/). However, I get an error if I copy-paste the code from this link to the Colab notebook:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils import model_to_dot

SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

Error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-819c3bda4aa6> in <module>()
      1 from IPython.display import SVG
----> 2 from keras.utils import model_to_dot
      3 
      4 SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))

ImportError: cannot import name 'model_to_dot'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

model_to_dot can be imported if you change line 2 with:

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import model_to_dot
```

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran, docs are up-to-date, and they reflect the latest API state. However, as of now the latest keras release is quite old 2.2.4 (Oct 3, 2018).  Here, is a corresponding [commit message](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/2e0de19d629e2eb5be4f614049e5f0d32887d155#diff-9f54a6fb7c27b254795b458e8e37948f). So they just need to release again!

Answer (score 1):

model_to_dot can be imported if you change line 2 with:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import model_to_dot
```